# На вход подаётся целое трёхзначное число, а затем цифра. Выведите true, если эта цифра является средней в числе (разряд десятков), и false - если нет

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value1 = Math.abs(input.nextInt());
        int value2 = Math.abs(input.nextInt());
         if(value1 >= 99 & value1 <= 1000){
         if((value1 % 100 / 10) == value2){
          System.out.println("true");
          }else{
          System.out.println("false");
          }
          }else{
          System.out.println("error");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста что не так

Comment: нет, это ВЫ подскажите что не так

Comment: Да не проходит 7 тест проверка на отрицательные числа

Comment: ну значит нужно добавить обработку отрицательных чисел, не? Вроде бы, это очевидно.\

Comment: и учитесь давать переменным такие имена, чтобы было понятно, что они содержат. Через неделю будете смотреть в свой код и думать, что же там в value1 и value2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том что ваша программа отвечает `true` вместо `error`
для `-99 9` и `99 9`. Вот это место: `value1 >= 99`.

А ещё `true` для `-1000 0` и `1000 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Ты невнимательно прочитал задание, диапазон проверки чисел должен быть трехзнаяным.

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value1 = Math.abs(input.nextInt());
        int value2 = Math.abs(input.nextInt());
         if(value1 > 99 & value1 < 1000){
         if((value1 % 100 / 10) == value2){
          System.out.println("true");
          }else{
          System.out.println("false");
          }
          }else{
          System.out.println("error");
    }
  }
}
```